# Is this nice extension of Mac OS 9 still available on OS X?

Tags: macos

There was an extension on Mac OS 9 system that I could not live without : This extension offered the following feature :

When a "Choose a file / folder" dialog box appeared, you were able to click on a "visible" opened window to make the selection box "jump" to that particular place in the tree structure of the disk (on the network).

Is there something like this on OS X ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [Default Folder X](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/).

Comment: Indeed ! Yes, Default folder that was it. But, Ouch, their prices are not nice :-/

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly the same but if you drag any file or folder to the dialog panel then it will jump to the location of the dropped item